# How to add a closure to jQuery .each function?

Tags: jquery, variables, each

I have a couple of links with two classes like this:

```
<a href="#" class="button post-12">Babylon</a>
<a href="#" class="button post-47">Sumer</a>
<a href="#" class="button post-87">Ur</a>
```

I wan't each of these buttons to hide a correlating post, for instance, clicking on the link with a class of "post-12" shall hide this:

```
<p id="post-12">Babylon was an aicient city...</p>
```

To make this happen I have this jQuery script. But it's always the post with id "post-87" that closes with all three buttons.

```
var secondClass;
$('.button').each(function(){
    secondClass = $(this).attr('class');
    secondClass = secondClass.replace('button ','');
    $(this).click(function(){
        $('#'+secondClass+'').hide();
    });
});
```

What am I doing wrong here? How to add a closure to jQuery .each function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the scope of your secondClass declaration:

```
$('.button').each(function(){
    var secondClass = $(this).attr('class');
    secondClass = secondClass.replace('button ','');
    $(this).click(function(){
        $('#'+secondClass+'').hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I think we can take advantage of -data in your scenario:

```
<a href="#" data-divid="post-12" class="button post-12">Babylon</a>
<a href="#" data-divid="post-47" class="button post-47">Sumer</a>
<a href="#" data-divid="post-87" class="button post-87">Ur</a>

$('.button').click(function(){
    var divtoclose = $(this).data("divid");
    $('#'+divtoclose).hide();
});
```